# How to get a math font that is much larger than Huge？

Tags: fonts, amsmath, nodes

My tex code is like this：

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw=none,fill=none] at (0,0){\includegraphics{one-inc.pdf}};
    \node[fill, circle, minimum size=5cm] at (10cm,3cm) {};
    \node at (0,3cm) {\Huge $\si{\angstrom}$};
    \node[font=\fontsize{52}{58}] at (0,5cm) {\Huge $\si{\angstrom}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The compiled result is as shown in the figure：
[image: node]

The size of my font should be at least the same size as the node. Now obviously \Huge cannot satisfy it. Please tell me how to make the font larger. For some reason I can't provide my pdf, I know the reason is because the pdf is too large.’

please what should i do

---

I tried the solution in this question, but it still failed. This is my test. Other letters did not become larger. How should I solve it?

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw=none,fill=none] at (0,0){\includegraphics{one-inc.pdf}};
    \node[fill, circle, minimum size=5cm] at (10cm,3cm) {};
    \node[font=\fontsize{200}{200}] at (0,5cm) { $K(\si{\angstrom}^{-1})$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: node2]

Comment: Your title says 'math font`, but your example uses a *text* font. These are two very different kettles of fish. Could you please clarify? Please note nobody can compile your example but you.

Comment: As David told you, `fix-cm` or use another font. You will still get issues with `cmex` and `\angstrom`, so read the warnings on the terminal.